# elements.style.backgroundColor returns undefined

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use javascript to see if a class has a specific background color but every time I tried something it always returned undefined. I have tried a lot of things so I'm at a loss here.

CSS

```
.ChangeColors {
    background-color: #ff801b;
    color:black;
}
```

Javascript

```
function ChangeColors(){
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('ChangeColors');
    if (all.style.backgroundColor == "#ff801b") {
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
          all[i].style.color = 'white';
          all[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
          all[i].style.color = 'black';
          all[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ff801b';
          console.log(help)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns the array of HTMLCollection, so you might to do all[index] and try it.

Comment: … and you can not read styles via `element.style`, if they were not set inline to begin with.

Comment: If you just need to switch between pre-defined colors, then this should rather not be done by looping through all relevant elements and checking on their color, but by changing the class of a common ancestor element, and letting your stylesheet do all the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use jQuery for such util functions like below

```
var color = $('.ChangeColors').css( "background-color" );
```

Now compare your value with **color** it should not return undefined

Answer (score 4):

You can have seperate classes for changing CSS properties like

```
.ChangeColors {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 color: black;
}

.orangecolor {
  background-color: #ff801b;
 }

.bluecolor {
 background-color: blue;
 color:white;
 }
```

and can loop through nodes and add/remove class according to the requirement

```
   function ChangeColors() {
     var all = document.querySelectorAll(".ChangeColors");
     for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
     if (all[i].classList.contains("orangecolor")) {
        all[i].classList.add("bluecolor");
     } else {
       all[i].classList.add("orangecolor");
    }
  }
 }
```

Check  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yd7j82p/) for it

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems.

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of `HTMLCollection`
2. `style` property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element.

   `<div style="color: red;"></div>`

   Your element does not have inline `stlye` attribute. So  `element.style.backgroundColor` does not work.
3. `element.style.backgroundColor` does not return always HEX color even though you set HEX color. On some browser, it returns RGB color.

---

This is a bad appraoch. However, if you like it, use `window.getComputedStyle(element)["background-color"]` and convert it to hex color if it is RGB and then compare.

```js
function ChangeColors() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('change-color');
  for (let element of elements) {
    var background = window.getComputedStyle(element)["background-color"]
    console.log(background)
  }
}
ChangeColors()
```

```css
.change-color {
  background-color: ##ff801b;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-color">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste deserunt officia voluptatum earum laboriosam? Est, ipsam. Ex veniam, incidunt, alias quasi aliquam sit eaque recusandae, expedita fugiat possimus a corrupti.
</div>
```

You may use two classes for applying color and  background.

```js
function ChangeColors() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('change-color');

  for (let element of elements) {
    if (element.classList.contains("bg-blue")) {
      element.classList.add('bg-orange');
    } else {
      element.classList.add('bg-blue')
    }
  }
}

ChangeColors()
```

```css
.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: #ff801b;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-color">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste deserunt officia voluptatum earum laboriosam? Est, ipsam. Ex veniam, incidunt, alias quasi aliquam sit eaque recusandae, expedita fugiat possimus a corrupti.
</div>


<div class="change-color bg-blue">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste deserunt officia voluptatum earum laboriosam? Est, ipsam. Ex veniam, incidunt, alias quasi aliquam sit eaque recusandae, expedita fugiat possimus a corrupti.
</div>
```

Read these for more info.

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

[How to compare a backgroundColor in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-a-backgroundcolor-in-javascript)

[style.backgroundColor doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852228/style-backgroundcolor-doesnt-work)

If you use jQuery.

[How can I compare two color values in jQuery/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377696/how-can-i-compare-two-color-values-in-jquery-javascript/11943970#11943970)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the whole jQ library you can do it with 
[getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
let all = document.querySelectorAll(".ChangeColors");

function ChangeColors() {
  for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    const { style } = all[i];
    if (
      window.getComputedStyle(all[i], false).backgroundColor ===
      "rgb(255, 128, 27)"
    ) {
      style.color = "white";
      style.background = "blue";
    } else {
      style.color = "black";
      style.background = "#ff801b";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-feistel-16l4m